# Does the temperature of a transformer affect the relationship between the induced voltage and primary current?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, inductance

I'm doing an experiment involving inductance between two coaxial solenoids of the same length where I measure the rms value of the alternating current through the outer solenoid and rms value of the induced voltage of the inner solenoid (as far as I know this is basically a transformer). I'm trying to figure out if an increase in the circuit's temperature will change the ratio between the induced (secondary) voltage and primary current ($\frac{V_s}{I_p}$).

I've found that the efficiency of a transformer decreases with heat due to 'resistive loss', as the heat causes the resistance to increase, changing the induced voltage (or something like that) where the loss can be found using the power equation $P_{loss}=I^2R$. Clearly the energy wasted by the system is affected so I tried to find a connection between the induced voltage and energy/efficiency of the system, which led me to the standard power equations $P_s=I_sV_s$ and $P_p=I_pV_p$.

Using these I formed the efficiency and equation and rearranged as such:
$$\frac{P_s}{P_p}=\frac{(I_s)(V_s)}{(I_p)(V_p)}$$.
$$\frac{V_s}{I_p}=\frac{(P_s)(V_p)}{(P_p)(I_s)}$$.

This shows that the efficiency ratio is a factor in determining the relationship but I figured maybe $\frac{V_p}{I_s}$ changes in such a way that $\frac{V_s}{I_p}$ stays the same. I also tried substituting $V_p=I_pR$ and $I_s=\frac{V_s}{R}$ (I believe resistance is constant but I might be wrong) which gives:
$$\frac{V_s}{I_p}=\sqrt{\frac{P_s}{P_p}}R$$.

This once again looks to me like the ratio should change with efficiency but I'm still unsure.